# Как собрать Jar в Jar?

Tags: java

Есть java класс, в нем есть код и импорты от одной jar библиотеки. Как мне собрать из них jar. Если компилить Main.java, то выходят ошибки не найденных классов. Как мне скомпилить все правильно?

В cmd.exe

Comment: Почитайте про classpath и используйте ключ **-cp** при компиляции

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел в папке build скомпиленный class Main.java, скомпилил либу, собираю через архивацию в zip без сжатия

Comment: стоит научиться пользоваться системами сборки

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/164837)

Comment: @VAndrJ, вроде как является? Хотя и так себе способ.

Comment: @Qwertiy Возможно и ошибся, но если читать вопрос и этот ответ, то похоже на дополнение вопроса.

Comment: @VAndrJ, он решил проблему тем, что вместо подключения её в проект, берёт недокомпиленное приложение, что-то с ним делает, а затем архивирует руками вместе с библиотекой, чтобы получилось что-то работающее. Так что скорее ответ, чем дополнение вопроса. Ну если я правильно понял, конечно :)

Comment: @Qwertiy, именно так :D